# Ember Component Attrs not Updated after setUpController

Tags: ember.js

I am facing a strange issue when accessing controller properties in the component.
I am setting up a controller property say 'selectedFilters' in thr route's setupController hook. I want this updated value within one of the components and I am passing this to an attribute of the component.
The issue is, the component is not getting the updated value(done in route's setupController) but it is getting its instantiated value.

I have tried observing the selectedFilters and  I am able to see the value updated. But the component's didUpdateAttrs is not triggered. Also, I have tried accessing this in init hook of the component but of no luck.

Note: If I set the value within controller, I have no issues. The issue is only when doing that in route's setup controller.

Comment: Can you post your code, route where you use setupController?

Comment: Or better, provide a not working ember-twiddle

Comment: Sounds to me you're observing it the wrong way in your component, do you use a computed property within the component which listens to the selectedFilters it got via the attributes?